# Is there any easy way (preferably in Chrome) of seeing which elements on an SSL-enabled page are Insecure?

Tags: html, google-chrome, ssl, google-chrome-extension

I have a secured page running and Chrome is showing me a red padlock instead of a green one, saying that there are insecure elements on the page.

I have pored over the source code, been through every tab and every item in WebKit Inspector - and I cannot find a single reference to `http://`.

Are there any WebKit Inspector tools/Chrome Extensions/easy ways to find out which elements are insuecure? Or do you have any advice as to which elements could likely be causing the problem?

I have found this extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hfoeodccbohfpgkldfcdknmlbbgmdcle which draws a green or red box around secure/insecure elements - but it's fairly poorly executed and makes it impossible to see what's insecure, as I can't find any elements like that.

Thanks!

**Update:** bizarrely when I load the same page in an Incognito window I start getting the green padlock. I went back to the original window and tried disabling every Chrome extension then reloading, but that didn't make any difference. I think it might just be a bit of a Chrome hiccup...

Comment: I'm afraid it's for a client who would not want me sharing it, and behind a login screen - sorry.

Comment: @JackWebb-Heller: It's not a Chrome hiccup (see below)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you visit a single insecure page in a Chrome session, any subsequent pages you visit on the same domain will also be marked as insecure. Your issue is most likely from an earlier page view on the same domain.

Answer (score 1):

The developer tools (F12) will list all resources that the current page is using.

Take a look at the console or resources tab.

Likely to be a link to a third party JavaScript library or image.

Comment: I'm convinced it's not. I've just used Chrome Developer Tools to search through every single resource on the page. Not a single one is coming via HTTP. The two external JS scripts I use both are going via HTTPS. A search through every element for "http://" only returns URLs in Javascript/CSS comments - which wouldn't count, would it..?

Comment: Shouldn't matter - What are the JavaScript urls?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).

> Fiddler is a Web Debugging Proxy which logs all HTTP(S) traffic between your computer and the Internet. Fiddler allows you to inspect traffic, set breakpoints, and "fiddle" with incoming or outgoing data. Fiddler includes a powerful event-based scripting subsystem, and can be extended using any .NET language.
>
> Fiddler is freeware and can debug traffic from virtually any application that supports a proxy, including Internet Explorer, Google Chrome, Apple Safari, Mozilla Firefox, Opera, and thousands more. You can also debug traffic from popular devices like Windows Phone, iPod/iPad, and others.